# ourvector<string> inputWords(string filename);

Tags: c++

```
ourvector<string> inputWords(string filename);
```

dose anyone has any idea what this code is doing.. I got that the first part is a vector but I don't have any idea what the `inputWords(..);` is doing.

```
vector<string> V; // This is what i know. which you insert the values in vector V and access them.
```

Comment: This line of code declares a function called `inputWords` that takes a single `string` parameter and returns a value of type `ourvector` which is templated with `string`.

Comment: I think you will need to include the implementation of inputWords to get a good answer.

Answer (score 2):

It simply declares a function named `inputWords` taking a single parameter of type `string` and returning a value of type `ourvector<string>`.

It is a (forward-)declaration without definition. The definition with the function body will be located somewhere else in the program code.

Without context there isn't much more to say.